# Using an Excel object with a conditional

Tags: excel, object, excel-formula, vba

Can you use Excel to store a condition requiring the an object to be inserted in a different field. Example if - cell B1 text = "yellow" then place "Caution Clip Art" in cell B30 and make the background yellow.

I'm thinking of JavaScript where you can just use an "if statement". But I've never run across needing this until now. Open to alternatives for a fairly large spreadsheet wanting to use a graphic or clip art.

[Graphic Sat Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDOg7.png)

Comment: If you aren't tied to the Caution Clip Art, you could set an if statement to return a value of 1 or 0 or some value that you could then use with a Conditional Formatting Rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use Conditional Formatting for this:

```
=IF(B1="yellow",1,if(B1="green",2,0))
```

Then, highlight the column. On the Home Tab > Conditional Formatting > Icon Sets > and choose one that fits your needs.

If you don't want to see the 0,1,2 values, set them to whatever background color you want. And if you want to set the background to yellow, you can use another Conditional format: Conditional Formatting > Highlight Cell Rules and set it up to color how you want.

Comment: Thank you - this is close enough to what I need to work. Perfect - thanks  a bunch. I can't upvote this but I will when I can...if I can.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need a user-defined function for this. Luckily, it's a simple one. Make sure it's within a Module.

```
Function ShowPic(PicFile As String) As Boolean
Dim AC As Range
On Error GoTo Done
Set AC = Application.Caller
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture PicFile, True, True, AC.Left, AC.Top, 200, 200
ShowPic = True
Exit Function
Done:
ShowPic = False
End Function
```

You can then call this function with =ShowPic("pathtofile.jpg"). You could also use it within an IF statement. So =IF(A2="yellow",ShowPic("caution.jpg"),IF(A2="green",ShowPic("greenlight.jpg")...

The background color can be changed with conditional formatting.